# Babel - Node modules with JSX syntax in .js files break compilation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, babeljs, react-native-web

I'm getting SyntaxError when importing a modules where JSX syntax is used within .JS files.

One example of this is "react-navigation"

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/ResourceSavingSceneView.js
SyntaxError: /Users/my_user/Projects/my-react-native-web-app/node_modules/@react-navigation/native/dist/ResourceSavingSceneView.js: Unexpected token(35:11)

  33 |     } = this.props;
  34 |
> 35 |     return <View style={styles.container} collapsable={false} removeClippedSubviews={Platform.OS === 'android' ? removeClippedSubviews: !isFocused && removeClippedSubviews}>
     |            ^
  36 |         <View style={this._mustAlwaysBeVisible() || isFocused ?styles.innerAttached : styles.innerDetached}>
  37 |           {awake ? <SceneView {...rest} navigation={childNavigation} /> : null}
  38 |         </View>
```

Below is my babel config:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        plugins: [
            [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
                {
                    loose: true
                }
            ],
            [
                "module-resolver",
                {
                    alias: {
                        "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
                    }
                }
            ]
        ],
        presets: [["react-app"], ["babel-preset-expo"]]
    };
};
```

Hope someone knows what is going on

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly tell webpack to transpile `react-navigation`.

```
      // Process JS with Babel.
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx|mjs)$/,
        include: [
          `${paths.appNodeModules}/react-navigation`,
```

References: [webpack.config.dev.js#L141](https://github.com/haruelrovix/gitphone/blob/8c0e6036d9231cc934285502528a2061b848ce2d/config/webpack.config.dev.js#L141)

Comment: This looked promising, but it didn't work. Also tried this but with "@react-navigation".